# Как обрабатывать огромные тексты php?

Tags: php

Может есть запрет на сервере, но не удается обработать текст размером более 4 мб. Что делать? Работает ли пхп с файлами большего объема?

Comment: А что, ошибка какаято? или угадывать? у меня работает норм

Comment: Думаю если нельзя никак увеличить размер памяти, выдаваемой на операцию (я хз как точнее описать), то думаю стоит читать файл по частям?

Comment: скорее всего нужно посмотреть на алгоритмы. Может там чтение файла через конкатенацию сделано (код условный):

    $s = "";
    while (!eof($f) {
      $line = readline($f);
      $s .= $line;
    }

то подобное будет сильно тормозить с увеличением размера.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Дело в php.ini похоже, действительно. Чего не в ответы писали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего нужно подшаманить php.ini, попробуйте увеличить 
memory_limit
и кинуть сюда лог ошибки.